# How do I properly use the length function in haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, primes

I am currently working on trying to find the number of primes between a range in haskell.  The program prints out the range of primes correctly. E.g countPrimesUntil 2 10 will print out [2, 3, 5, 7].  I am looking for the number 4 because that's how many primes is between 2 and 10.  How do I incorporate countPrimes correctly?

```
import Data.List

countPrimesUntil :: Integral a=> a -> a -> [a]
countPrimesUntil a b = takeWhile (<= b) $ dropWhile (< a) $ sieve [2..]
    while sieve (n:ns) = n:sieve [m | m <- ns, m `mod` n /= 0]

countPrimes n = length([x | x <- [2..n], countPrimesUntil x])
```

Comment: `while` should be `where`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`countPrimesUntil` is misnamed; it doesn't count anything. Rather, it produces a list of primes between `a` and `b`, inclusive.

All you need to do is apply `length` to the result of `countPrimesUntil`, when given arguments `2` and `n`.

```
countPrimes n = length (countPrimesUntil 2 n)
-- countPrimes = length . countPrimesUntil 2
```

Answer (score 1):

In that case the `countPrimes` calls `countPrimesUntil 2 n`, and determines it length, so:

```
countPrimes n = length (countPrimesUntil 2 n)
```